# Go image manipulation

Tags: image, go, colors, rgba

I need to load an image and search for colors and replace them. For example on an image I need to search for all red pixels and convert them to purple.

I am doing the following (`img` is a valid `.png` image):

```
func colorize(img image.Image) {
    b := image.NewRGBA(img.Bounds())
    draw.Draw(b, b.Bounds(), img, image.ZP, draw.Src)
    for x := 0; x < b.Bounds().Dx(); x++ {
        for y := 0; y < b.Bounds().Dy(); y++ {
            log.Println(b.At(x, y).RGBA())
        }
    }
}
```

Thing is `img.At().RGBA()` doesn't seem to return the proper R, G, B, A codes? I am getting numbers bigger than 255 for example.

So how should I read all the image pixels while being able to know the x and y position of them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`img.At().RGBA()` is [`Color.RGBA()`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/color/#Color). Quoting its doc:

```
// RGBA returns the alpha-premultiplied red, green, blue and alpha values
// for the color. Each value ranges within [0, 0xffff], but is represented
// by a uint32 so that multiplying by a blend factor up to 0xffff will not
// overflow.
//
// An alpha-premultiplied color component c has been scaled by alpha (a),
// so has valid values 0 <= c <= a.
```

Components returned by `RGBA()` are in range `0..0xffff`, not `0..0xff`, and they are also alpha-premultiplied.

#### Manual decoding

One way to get back the red, green, blue components in the `0..255` range is to shift right by 8 for example:

```
r, g, b, a := b.At(x, y).RGBA()
r, g, b, a = r>>8, g>>8, b>>8, a>>8
log.Println(r, g, b) // Now in range 0..255
```

#### Converting to `color.RGBA`

Another way is to convert the color to [`color.RGBA`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/color/#RGBA) which is a struct, containing the components plain and simple:

```
type RGBA struct {
        R, G, B, A uint8
}
```

Since you are using [`image.NewRGBA()`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/#NewRGBA) which returns an image of type [`image.RGBA`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/#RGBA), the colors returned by the `Image.At()` method will be of dynamic type `color.RGBA`, so you can simply use a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions):

```
rgbacol := b.At(x, y).(color.RGBA)
log.Println(rgbacol.R, rgbacol.G, rgbacol.B, rgbacol.A)
```

In general (if image is not of type `image.RGBA`), `Image.At()` may or may not be of concrete type `color.RGBA`.

So in the general case you need to convert the color to a value of type `color.RGBA`. Conversions between color models are modeled by [`color.Model`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/color/#Model), and the `image/color` package has predefined converters. What you need is `color.RGBAModel`. `color.RGBAModel.Convert()` will return a `color.Color` value whose dynamic type is surely `color.RGBA`.

Example using `color.RGBAModel`:

```
var c color.Color
c = color.Gray{160}

rgbacol := color.RGBAModel.Convert(c).(color.RGBA)

fmt.Println(rgbacol.R, rgbacol.G, rgbacol.B, rgbacol.A)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/AXA8PYPKJ3)):

```
160 160 160 255
```

So in your loop do:

```
rgbacol := color.RGBAModel.Convert(b.At(x, y).(color.RGBA)
// rgbacol is a struct of type color.RGBA, components are in range 0..255
```

**Note:**

Above solutions still give you back the alpha pre-multiplied components. If you want to undo the alpha pre-multiplication, you may use `color.NRGBAModel` converter (instead of `color.RGBAModel`).